# ¿Como eliminar un registro de una tabla con Laravel?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, laravel, angular

en mi aplicación los usuarios logueados a través de un botón se registran a una actividad, cuando hacen click en el botón, se envía la información del usuario y de la actividad a un tabla de la base de datos.

Lo anterior funciona de la siguiente manera:

controlador Laravel:

```
public function eventoRegistrado(Request $request){
    $eventoRegistrado = new Registration();
    $eventoRegistrado->user_id          = $request->user_id;
    $eventoRegistrado->event_id         = $request->event_id;
    $eventoRegistrado->nombre_asistente = $request->nombre_asistente;
    $eventoRegistrado->nombre_evento    = $request->nombre_evento;
    $eventoRegistrado->save();   
}
```

funcion Javascript:

```
$http.post("/eventoRegistrado", {user_id: $scope.user_id, event_id: $scope.evento_id, 
                        nombre_asistente: $scope.nombre_asistente, nombre_evento: $scope.nombre_evento})
```

vista:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click='registrarEvento("{{$event->name}}", "{{$event->id}}", "{{Auth::user()->id}}", "{{Auth::user()->name}}")'>Registrarme en este evento.</button>
```

La idea es que ademas de el botón de registro, también exista un botón para eliminar el registro, pero no se como lograr crear una función para eliminar el registro ya hecho.

Comment: Entonces es hacer la funcionalidad de eliminar un registro? si es así para poder eliminar un registro debes de tener cargado primeramente la lista de registros con sus respectivos datos(requieres de su `identificador` para poder eliminarlo) botón de eliminar y hacer la funcionalidad tanto en el frontend(consumir un servicio donde mande el id a eliminar) y en el backend caches el id y lo elimines, no olvides mandarle el mensaje de éxito o error al cliente.

Comment: Gracias por responder, si, en teoría eso eso lo que hay que hacer, el problema es como hacer la función en el controlador, que no se como implementarla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria crear una ruta en tu aplicación Laravel, según la documentación acerca de HTTP se define un conjunto de métodos de petición https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods  para este caso seria un `DELETE` (borra un recurso en específico) deberas registrar la nueva ruta, en el directorio `/app/Http` de tu proyecto de Laravel encontraras el archivo `routes.php`.  Debes agregar la siguiente linea recuerda ponerle la ruta, el controlador y la función según tu consideración.

```
Route::delete('/api/v1/eventos/{id}', 'Eventos@destroy');
```

Creamos una función en el controlador que se va a encargar de recibir el id y eliminarlo regresando el mensaje de exito a Angular

```
public function destroy(Request $request) {
    $evento = Registration::find($request->input('id'));
    $evento->delete();
    return "evento eliminado con exito";
}
```

En tu vista...teniendo en cuenta que ya hiciste el GET de la lista de eventos y lo mostramos en una tabla

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in eventos">
        <td>{{x.id }}</td>
        <td>{{x.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="btnEliminar(x.id)">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

En tu controlador de tu proyecto Angular crea la función de eliminar, el cual recibe el id a eliminar y hace la petición a Laravel.

```
$scope.btnEliminar = function (_id) {
    $http({
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: 'http://urldelaapi.com/api/v1/eventos/' + _id
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
    }).error(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert('Hubo un error');
    });
}
```

Puedes basarte en este ejemplo: https://tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-angularjs-tutorial

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, fue de gran ayuda.

Comment: otro detalle extra para tu solucion es que uses borrados logicos con deleted_at()